# Azure - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, azure, model-view-controller

I have a problem with MVC web site after publishing to Azure.

While testing locally everything works fine, but after I publish all pages with models stopped working and giving the "NullReferenceException" on lines, where I use models, like

```
@For Each item In Model
```

May be I forgot to add something in Web.config?

P.S. It will be perfect if you show me how to debug azure web site with breakpionts.

upd:

NewsContoller.vb

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports website.Models.Objects.Collections
Imports website.Models.Logic
Imports website.Models.Objects

Namespace Controllers
    Public Class NewsController
        Inherits Controller

        ' GET: News
        Function Index(Optional ByVal id As Integer = 0) As ActionResult
            Dim model As New NewsList
            model = NewsManager.GetList(id)
            Return View(model)
        End Function

        ' GET: News/Details/id
        Function Details(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
            Dim model As New News
            model = NewsManager.GetItem(id)
            Return View(model)
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

News/Index.vbhtml

```
@ModelType List(Of website.Models.Objects.News)

<div style="width:100%; border-top:1px solid #e1e1e1;"></div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <h2 style="margin-top:0;">News</h2>
    <div style="position:relative;">
        <ul id="news-container" style="visibility:hidden;">
            @For Each item In Model
                @<li>
                     <a href="/News/Details/@item.NewsID">
                         <figure class="tint">
                             <img src='~/Uploads/News/@String.Concat(item.Pictures(0).PictureGUID,".jpg")' width="243" />
                         </figure>
                         <div class="date-container">@item.PostDate.ToString("%d")<br />@item.PostDate.ToString("MMM")</div>
                         <h3>@item.Title</h3>
                         <p style="width:233px; padding:0 5px; margin:5px 0;">@item.Description</p>
                     </a>
                </li>
            Next
        </ul>
    </div>
```

NewsManager.GetList() returns a List(of News) from database.

Comment: Is there any way your model is actually returned as null from the controller? How did you publish your website? Did you previously publish it or is this a fresh one? You can debug by going to View->Server Explorer-> Websites->select a website->Attach Debugger. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/

Comment: No way. These pages work locally. I publish it from the Visual Studio. I previously published it, but w/o pages, that use models. I tried to make it, I have window "Retrieving remote debugger setting" then browser window opened and thats all.

Comment: Do note to set to debugger mode in the settings when you are publishing. Also might want check the delete old files when publishing checkbox in the settings aswell.

Comment: Still does not work for me. Using some test pages i understood, that controller cannot access model. Definitely something does not work inside model. But i still cannot debug with breakpoints.

Comment: For the sake of the symantics, controller cant access a model, a controller creates a model. Views are the one whos accessing it(via razor engine). Post more code, lets see where it goes. Also try to write @Foreach var item in Model??new List<object>() so it will run

Comment: I added some code from my controller and view. In model functions just gets data from DB and generates a list.

Comment: Can problems with creating model appear because of default namespace? Locally i have website.*** and i don't know what is in azure project. Project name is other and may be root namespace is other too?

Answer (score 0):

Although it not possible to tell from with out seeing your code for the `NewsManager.GetList()` the `NewsManager.GetList(id)` likely returns a `null` object instead of the a blank list.  This is likely due to the way the `NewManager` handles either a bad database connection or your database table not having any data in it after it was created in Azure.

You can replicate the issue by doing the following:

```
Function Index(Optional ByVal id As Integer = 0) As ActionResult
        Dim model As New NewsList
        model = Nothing 'simulate NewsManager.GetList(id) returning null 
        Return View(model)
End Function
```

As @misha130 mentioned in his comment, you will find detailed instructions on how to debug websites in Azure [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/).

The basic steps are:

1. Open the web project
2. Set a breakpoint on the line in question.
3. Right click on the project and select publish.
4. For the correct Profile, Click the Settings tab, and change Configuration to Debug, and then click Publish.
5. In Server Explorer expand Azure, expand Web Apps, right-click your web app, and click Attach Debugger. (There might be a small delay)